# Listagg delimeter is geting printed is there are no values selected

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, listagg

I am using `LISTAGG()` function in my select statement in a procedure such as

```
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(LISTAGG(a.student1||':'||a.score||'+') 
                WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY a.roll_no) OVER (PARTITION BY a.class)
```

If my select statement has not null values then i get
for eg: `ABC:100`

But if the select is empty then i get
for eg:  `:`

I wanted it to be null if there are no rows selected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the expression you're aggregating returns a non-NULL value whether or not the values you're concatenating are `NULL`.  My guess is you want something like

```
listagg(case when a.student1 is not null
             then a.student1||':'||a.score||'+'
             else null
          end)
```

If you can have a `null` value for `student1` but a non-NULL value for `score`, you'd need to adjust the `case` statement to specify what you want to happen in that case (do you want the ":" and the "+"?  Just the "+"?)

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `REPLACE` is incomplete. Also, is `'+'` really supposed to be concatenated? What string separates values, then?

```
   REPLACE (
      LISTAGG (a.student1 || ':' || a.score, '+')    --> removed || for the + sign
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.roll_no)
         OVER (PARTITION BY a.class),
      ':', '')                                       --> missing arguments for REPLACE
```

If that's still not what you asked, please, provide sample test data and desired output.

Comment: this works but if i remove the || then a character is missing in my result. for eg: if my result should be ahd:100+acz:77  i am getting ahd:100+acz:7. a 7 in the end is missing